# GRBL issue with PWM on Arduino CNC Shield

Tags: arduino, cnc

**PWM with laser plugged in**
[image]

**PWM with laser unplugged**

[image]

I'm having some issues with my PWM laser control. When I connect the laser, the voltage on the Z+ pin goes up to around 1V which is undefined in TTL logic. This results in my laser never turning on. The images show Analog (blue) and Digital (white) output of Z+. This is happening on my Arduino UNO with CNC shield.
I also have a 3018 with a custom controller board. If I plug the laser to that board it works as expected, so I'm ruling out the laser as the problem.

Comment: Depending on the actual arduino cnc board you have, my interpretation is the Z+ output is for a stepper motor. If this is the case, then i’m not surprised it doesn’t work. You might want to provide more information in your question so we can give more precise answers.

Comment: I have a regular Arduino UNO with a CNC shield V3 like the one in this website: https://naylampmechatronics.com/ardusystem-shields/68-shield-cnc-v3-grbl.html

Comment: You should put the information in your question, not as a comment. Have you built GRBL to make Z+ an output? I would’ve thought this question would be better served on the grbl forums.

Comment: The Z Axis is completely unsuitable for driving a Laser. You could use the Spindle enable signal which would probably work but might be inverted. You need to provide more details for any reasonable answer.